# How to get the current id of model from another controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to get the `id` of my model using different controller so I can `sync` this to my pivot table. I can get the `id` of my Model using this.

```
class DocumentController extends Controller
{
//READ
public function readDocuments($id)
{
    //Find the document in the database and save as var.
    $document = Document::find($id);
    $getId = $document->id;

    echo $getId;
}
}
```

But when I try to get the `id` from another controller it gives me a error.

> ErrorException in CommentController.php line 18:
>   Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::postComments()

Here is my Controller for getting the current model. Can I access the `var` `$getId` from different controller? Any tips how can I get the current `id` of the model?

```
class CommentController extends Controller
{

    public function postComments(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $this->validate($request,
        [
            'comment' => 'required',
        ]);

        $commentObject = new Comment();
        $documentObject = Document::find($id);//GET THE CURRENT ID OF THE (MODEL) DOCUMENT
        $aa = $documentObject->id;

        echo $aa;       

        $commentObject->comment = $request->comment;
        $commentObject->save();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<!--DOCUMENT CONTROLLER-->
<div class = "col-md-6">

    <div class = "form-group">

        <textarea id = "content">{{ $document->content }}</textarea>

    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">

        <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-success">Approve</button>

    </div>
</div>

<!--COMMENT CONTROLLER-->
<div class = "col-md-6">
    <form class = "form-vertical" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('comments') }}">

        <div class = "form-group {{ $errors->has('comment') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

            <label for = "comment">Comment:</label>
            <textarea class = "form-control" rows = "4" id = "comment" name = "comment" placeholder = "Leave a feedback"></textarea>

            @if ($errors->has('comment'))
                <span class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('comment') }}</span>
            @endif

        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">

            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Comment</button>

        </div>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

    </form>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to passed `$id` in my function. But when I to check it. It says. This error happened when I tried to passed the `$id` in my parameter.

> ErrorException in CommentController.php line 19:
>   Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::postComments()

CommentController:

```
 public function postComments(Request $request, $id)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'comment' => 'required',
    ]);

    $commentObject = new Comment();
    $documentObject = Document::find($id);//GET THE CURRENT ID OF THE (MODEL) DOCUMENT

    echo $documentObject;

    $commentObject->comment = $request->comment;
    $commentObject->save();
}
```

I tried to `die and dump` the `$documentObject` but it doesn't print anything.

Routes:

```
//FOR DOCUMENT CONTROLLER

Route::get('/document/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@readDocuments',
    'as' => 'document.read',
    'middleware' => 'auth',
]);

//FOR COMMENT CONTROLLER

Route::post('/comments',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@postComments',
    'as' => 'comments',
]);
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
//DocumentController

Route::get('/document/{id}',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@readDocuments',
    'as' => 'document.read',
    'middleware' => 'auth',
]);

//CommentController

Route::post('/document/{id}/comments',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@postComments',
    'as' => 'comments',
]);
```

View:

```
<!--COMMENT CONTROLLER-->
<div class = "col-md-6">
    <form class = "form-vertical" method = "post" action = "{{ route ('/comment/{id}') }}">

        <div class = "form-group {{ $errors->has('comment') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

            <label for = "comment">Comment:</label>
            <textarea class = "form-control" rows = "4" id = "comment" name = "comment" placeholder = "Leave a feedback"></textarea>

            @if ($errors->has('comment'))
                <span class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('comment') }}</span>
            @endif

        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">

            <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Comment</button>

        </div>

        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "{{ Session::token() }}">

    </form>
</div>
```

But it can't recognize the route that I registered. It always says.

> Route [/comment/{id}] not defined. (View: C:\Users\JohnFrancis\LaravelFrancis\resources\views\document\read.blade.php)

Comment: You can pass it from your view, is there any view share with us

Comment: @Iftikharuddin Sure. I updated my post. My view has also a different controller. Please see.

Comment: According to you, you're not passing the id to the 'comments' route. Do that and you won't have any problems. i.e. `Route::post('/comments/{id}'`

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata Yes I already did that. How can I passed that in my `action` should it be like these? `action = "{{ route ('comments/{id}') }}"`. I tried this but it say's `Route [comments/{id}] not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

laravel can find automatic document :
define route like this :

```
Route::post('/document/{document}/comments',
[
'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@postComments',
'as' => 'comments',
]);
```

and in controller :

```
public function postComments(Request $request, Document $document)
```

laravel get document automatic.

set form action like :

http://www.ADDRESS.com/document/2/comments

to send comment to document with id 2.

Comment: I tried to `echo` the `$documentObject` but I can't get the value. Please see my updated post.

Comment: use `Document::find($id)->first()` and use `dd` function instead `echo` to see Document detail

Comment: It still give me the same error. When I tried to past `$id` in my parameter. I'm just trying to get the `id` of `Document` model so I can sync it into pivot table.

Comment: Are u sure document with that id exist..!? use this line to test document model `Documnet::all()`

Comment: Yes because this is the current view that I'm using. I tried to check this in my `Document Controller` this works. But when I tried this from another controller it doesn't work

Comment: change route for send comment to this : `Route::post('/document/{id}/comments',
[
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@postComments',
    'as' => 'comments',
]);` and in comment form set action and put document id in {id} part.

Comment: Already did what you said. Is this correct? I passed this in my `action`. `action = "{{ route ('comments/{id}') }}"` But it says `Route [comments/id] not defined.`

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. You get the output that I want. Why should I passed the `{document}` in `Route::post('/document/{document}/comments'`? and how my routes in form will be?

Comment: this is one to many relation (document has many comment and every comment belongs to a document) . routine way that show comment form in document page . and when load document you can access document id in blade view . u just need set action to form like `actione="{{ url('/document/'.$document->id.'/comments') }}"` in blade file

Comment: I'm already near to my output! I just needed to get the current document in my url.  I tried this `$documentObject = Document::find($document);` and die and dump this to `dd ($documentObject);` But it prints me a null in the screen. Thanks!!

Comment: don,t need find document . if use postcomment like answer , in `dd($document)` must be see document detail . be careful set document id in right place and don,t change name of variable in route and function input.

Comment: Oh I see I just wanted to get the document `id` and insert this into my `comment_user` pivot table. Can you explained the form routes` that you changes. Why I need to put `dot` in `/document/'.$document->id.'/comments`?

Comment: for one to many relation you don,t need pivot table.just add row in comment table with document_id name . i try use form action in blade file  and when try use address with variable need dot to connect string and variable .

Comment: Oh I made a many to many relation and I linked document_id in my pivot table and I thought it doesn't make sense much better if you linked this into comments table. Do I need to make a thread table for the comments thread? Thanks!

Comment: i think need more table for handle this . just add document_id row . i think this is better way.

Comment: i think need more table for handle this . just add document_id row . i think this is better way.